# NSMutableArray removeObject is not calling my custom isEqual

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I have a class that I'm using to pass a selector through with a text label:

```
@interface TableLink : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger identifier;
@property (nonatomic) SEL selector;
@end
@implementation TableLink
- (id) initWithName: (NSString*) name identifier: (NSInteger) identifier selector: (SEL) selector
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.name = name;
        self.identifier = identifier;
        self.selector = selector;
    }

    return self;
}

- (BOOL) isEqual: (id) anObject
{
    if (self == anObject)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([anObject isKindOfClass: [self class]])
    {
        return [self.name isEqualToString: [anObject name]];
    }
    else if ([anObject isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
    {
        return [self.name isEqualToString: anObject];
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (NSUInteger) hash
{
    return [self.name hash];
}

@end
```

I set up a mutable array of these objects like so:

```
+ (NSMutableArray*) buttonNames
{
    NSArray* names = [self determineActiveNames];
    NSMutableArray* buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: names.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.count; i++)
    {
        NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"show%@", names[i]];
        s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
        SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(s);
        TableLink* tl = [[TableLink alloc] initWithName: names[i] identifier: i selector: sel];
        [buttons addObject: tl];
    }

    return buttons;
}
```

Here's how I call the removal:

```
- (void) hideEntry: (NSString*) entry
{
    [self.buttons removeObject: entry];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But when I try to remove one with `[self.buttons removeObject: someNSString];` it doesn't remove anything from my array. I put a breakpoint in my `isEqual:` call, and it's not getting called. Am I missing something to get it to use my equality test or does `[NSMutableArray removeObject:]` not use `isEqual:` (the documentation says it does)?

When I replace the call to `removeObject:` with the following, it removes my entry as expected. It doesn't call my `isEqual:` or `hash`, obviously, but it gets the results I want. I would still like to know why it's not working though, in case I need to override isEqual in the future.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.buttons.count; i++)
{
    if ([[self.buttons[i] name] isEqualToString: entry])
    {
        [self.buttons removeObjectAtIndex: i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try implementing `-(NSUInteger)hash` too, in such a way that if the objects are equal, the hashes are equal (but not necessarily vice-versa) - you could just start with `return 0` to test.

Comment: Is the `name` in `[self.buttons removeObject: name]` an instance of TableLink or NSString?

Comment: It doesn't work because you're passing in a string to hideEntry: whereas your array contains TableLink objects, so of course they will never be equal. I'm not sure why your isEqual override isn't being called.

Comment: @rdelmar The `isEqual:` method works just fine actually. When I call it directly, it does what I expect, because I'm expecting an `NSString` for the parameter. The question I'm asking is why isn't `removeObject:` calling `isEqual:` like the docs say it should.

Answer (score 1):

You must also implement the `hash` method whenever you implement `isEqual:`.

Two objects that are considered equal MUST also return the same `hash` value.

You could do something as simple as:

```
- (NSUInteger)hash {
    return [self.name hash];
}
```

BTW - your `isEqual:` method is all wrong. It needs to be:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject {
    if (anObject == self) {
        return YES;
    } else if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        // This should probably also compare the identifier and maybe the selector too
        return [self.name isEqualToString:[anObject name]];
    } else if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        // Allow for comparison with a string
        return [self.name isEqualToString:(NSString *)anObject];
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

As you had it, you attempt to compare `self.name` to whatever object is being compared. Since you have an array of `TableLink` objects, `self.name` was being compared to `TableLink` objects. They will never be equal.

Comment: I'm passing a string to the removeObject call, so it should be the same parameter passed to the isEqual call, allowing me to compare a string to a string. But the issue isn't that the call isn't working, it's that isEqual isn't getting called at all. I had the hash function in there as well, and the call still never happened.

Comment: You really shouldn't be passing in a string to `removeObject:` if the array contains `TableLink` objects but see my updated `isEqual:` to allow for that.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the contents of `isEqual:` at the moment. I'm concerned about the fact that it doesn't get called.

Comment: Did you add the `hash` method like I showed? If show, update your question to show the code that calls `removeObject:`.

Comment: Even with the `hash` method and the overkill `isEqual:` method, my breakpoint on `[buttons removeObject: someNSString]` fires, but the breakpoints in `hash` and `isEqual:` do not.

Comment: And you still haven't posted the code where you actually call `removeObject:`. Please do so.

Comment: Have you verified that at the time you call your `hideEntry:` method that `self.buttons` isn't `nil`?

Comment: Yes. The array gets built in `viewDidLoad`, and it's displaying data in the table view.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Is it set when `hideEntry:` is called?

Comment: As I said, "yes". I also added some related information, so I could get past the minimum character requirement without writing a bunch of gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

You think there's a TableLink object in the mutable array, you pass it's name as an NSString*, and you think removeObject will call [someTableLink isEqual: someString] to find the TableLink object to remove. But it's just as likely that it calls [someString isEqual: someTableLink], calling the NSString isEqual instead.

What you do is just dangerous and will get you into trouble. If you are sure that button names are unique, put the links into an NSDictionary with the name as the key.

Comment: According to the Apple documentation, `removeObject:` calls `indexOfObject:`, which calls `isEqual:` on the items in the Array, passing `anObject` as the parameter. So it does work the way I'm assuming.

Comment: Well, apparently not. An isEqual: method that isn't symmetric, and that isn't consistent with the hash method is asking for Trouble with a capital T. Believing documentation that claims to tell you about implementation details that are nobody's business contrary to evidence that is wrong is daft. If the documentation was right, then your isEqual method would be called. It doesn't get called, so the documentation is wrong. By the way, I just tested it. isEqual is sent to the object that is removed, and indexOfObject isn't called.

Comment: The documentation is even more wrong: removeObject starts testing with the _last_ object, not the first. Which makes sense since stack-like operations will run in constant time that way.